# How to exchange strings in source files with the corresponding translated version from a Multilizer project file?

Tags: delphi, internationalization, translation

We have a large application, developed in Delphi, that initially was developed in Norwegian. At one point we decided that we needed to translate the application to English, Swedish and Polish. We used Multilizer for this task. The application is still developed in Norwegian, and we translate new strings when we release new versions.

Now we have decided to make English the native language of the application, so that new strings, captions etc. in our application should be entered in English in the source files, and translated to Norwegian, Swedish and Polish with Multilizer. Is there a way to replace all existing strings in .pas and .dfm files with the translated versions from the Multilizer project file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a resource file with the all the translated strings, then in your program you load the required string from the resource file. You don't say how many strings there are (in one language) which may be critical.

Let's say that you need to include a string like 'Press any key to continue'. The resource file will contain the above string, numbered 1, like this:

```
STRINGTABLE {
1, "Press any key to continue"
}
```

Then add to the file a string for the Norwegian version (numbered 1001), the Swedish version (numbered 2001) and the Polish version (numbered 3001). This scheme allows you 999 strings in each language.

In your program, you will include a line like

```
caption:= GetResString (n, lang);
```

where n is the number of the string and lang is the number of the language. This is the ASCII version of GetResString

```
Function GetResString (i, alang: integer): string;
var
 buffer: array [0..400] of char;
 ls: integer;

begin
 result:= '';
 ls:= loadstring (hinstance, i + alang * 1000, buffer, sizeof (buffer));
 if ls <> 0 then result:= buffer
end;
```

To compile the resource file, use brcc32. If you need Unicode, then this program is probably no good; there is another resource compiler called GoRC which produces unicode resource files. The unicode version of GetResString is as follows

```
function LoadResW (id, lang: integer): WideString;
const
 maxlength = 1024;

var
 l: integer;

begin;
 setlength (result, maxlength);
 l:= loadstringw (hinstance, lang * 1000 + id,
     pwidechar (result), length (result));
 if l > 0
  then setlength (result, l)
  else result:= ''
end;
```